# Web pages won't load in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, internet-connection

I have windows xp on my laptop and it is connected to the internet through wifi and everything was working fine, but now web pages won't load at all, the network connection is fine, but when i open any web page in any browser it keeps loading and loading, but the page content don't show.

I tried clearing the cache and temp files, repairing the network connection,  and even reinstalling windows xp with no luck.

Can you help me fix this?

Comment: Using a command prompt, can you ping www.yahoo.com?

Comment: No, the request is timing out.

Comment: Your DNS settings are probably wrong. You can see what your DNS settings are for each interface (WiFi, Ethernet, etc.) at a command prompt by entering "IPCONFIG /ALL"

Comment: Once you find what your DNS servers are set to, see if you can ping them. If not, check that your ISP is working by connecting an Ethernet cable from the modem to the laptop and see if you can get on the internet. There are public DNS servers you can try using manually. Google has some (8.8.8.8 & 8.8.4.4) and OpenDNS has some as well (https://use.opendns.com/#winxp).

Comment: Before running a cable, just try pinging 8.8.8.8. If you can ping it successfully, then it's definitely a DNS issue.

Comment: As I'm sure you know, Windows XP is long past its end of life and it is no longer remotely secure in a networked environment.

Comment: Ok, i will try and tell you the results soon.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton This laptop is kinda my backup laptop and it's an old laptop that can't handle windows 7

Comment: I tried changing the dns to google's dns but no change eventhough i can ping it.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried resetting your modem and/or router? You can reset them by unplugging them for about 15 seconds or so and then plugging them back in, which can sometimes help to resolve connection related issues.

Did you recently install or change any software or hardware, which you think may have caused this issue?

Comment: I have internet on my mobile and it's using the same network.

Comment: I tried turning the router off and on again with no luck,  and i didn't change anything in the laptop  recently.

Answer (score -1):

If you are power cycling your equipment, you want to bring it up in a specific order. Shut off your modem, router and laptop. Then bring up your modem. Wait a few minutes until the Internet light comes on. Then bring up the router. Once it is up, finally bring up your laptop.

Each device relies on the previous one, so you have to bring them up in order.

Comment: I tried the connection with another laptop and it's the same, the strange thing is that the internet is working on our mobiles but it's not working on our laptops.

Comment: Are you sure the mobiles are using your Wi-Fi and not falling back to the cell tower connection?

Comment: Yes i'm sure, i only have what's app on my data plan.

Comment: This isn't true. Each device can communicate with each other started in any order. This is the stuff what Spectrum and Comcast employees tell people to do when they don't know how to fix something lmao